# UDP ERROR WSAECONNRESET WINSOCK

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, winsock

server -  send to this place

client - current local place

Im run  mirrored host and client with minor changes code.

Hello, i have this code the problem is when i add on host side

```
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(27016);
server.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr("169.254.57.24"); 
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_port = htons(27015);
client.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

and this code on client side

```
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(27015);
server.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr("169.254.200.200"); 
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_port = htons(27016);
client.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY;
```

packets dont receive on both sides because WSAGetLastError()==WSAECONNRESET is TRUE on client side, but for logical it must work because i'm use continue when (WSAGetLastError()==WSAECONNRESET) its just ignor when we cant send on client to server. So when i use sendto on client side packet cant be delivered WSAECONNRESET grow up and im ignore this error, but problem is i cant recieve host packets. RECFROM all time catch error. But if i change client.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY; on host side it will work on both direction. Question why i cant send packe in one direction when i send packet to nonexistent socket.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 256


sig_atomic_t volatile stop = 0;
void sig_handler(int signum);
DWORD WINAPI handle_request(LPVOID param);


// holds data from the client
char send_buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "TEST MESSAGE CLIENT";
char receive_buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";


int server_length; 

// sockets which listens for a client
// and socket which represents the client
SOCKET server_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET client_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct sockaddr_in server;              /* Information about the server */
struct sockaddr_in client;              /* Information about the client */


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

WSADATA wsa_data;
HRESULT result;
HANDLE hThread;
// register signal SIGINT and signal handler  
signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);





// initializing sockets
// it has two main purposes
// 1. specify which version you want (2.2)
// 2. load the winsock dll into your process
result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa_data);
if(result != 0)  {
    printf("WSAStartup error: %d.\n", result);
    return 1;
}

///////////////////// send socket START

    /* Clear out server struct */
memset((void *)&server, 0 , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));


    /* Set family and port */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(27016);//27016
server.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr("169.254.57.24");         //INADDR_ANY;         //  inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


///////////////////// send socket END


//////////////////// recv socket START

/* Clear out server struct */
memset((void *)&client, 0 , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

/* Open a datagram socket */
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create socket.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(0);
}



/* Set family and port */
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_port = htons(27015);
client.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("127.0.0.1");//inet_addr("127.0.0.1");///INADDR_ANY;              

    /* Bind address to socket */
if (bind(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind name to socket.\n");
    closesocket(client_socket);

    WSACleanup();
    exit(0);
} 

///////////////////// recv socket END

hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex ( NULL, 0, reinterpret_cast<unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)>(handle_request), (void*)send_buffer, 0, NULL);



if (!hThread)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at CreateThread(): " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(client_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

while(!stop)  {

if (sendto(client_socket, send_buffer, (int)strlen(send_buffer) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "Error transmitting data.\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    continue;
    closesocket(client_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(0);
} 

static int c = 0;
send_buffer[0] = char(++c);
send_buffer[1] = 'A';
send_buffer[2] = '\0';
std::cout << "SEND NUMBER: "<<(int)send_buffer[0] << send_buffer[1] <<  std::endl;
Sleep(1000);



} 

 WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
     closesocket(client_socket);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

   WSACleanup();


return 0;
}

void sig_handler(int signum){
if (signum == SIGINT){
    stop = 1;
    printf("Shutting down the server!\n");
}
}

DWORD WINAPI handle_request(LPVOID param)
{
/* Receive time */
int iResult;


do
{
    iResult = 
// 1c recvfrom ( client_socket, (char *)&receive_audio, (int)sizeof(receive_audio), 0, 0, 0); //(struct sockaddr *)&server, &server_length
recvfrom ( client_socket, (char *)&receive_buffer, (int)sizeof(receive_buffer), 0, 0, 0);
    if (iResult <= 0)
    {
    if  (WSAGetLastError()==WSAECONNRESET)
        continue;
        printf("Error when connecting! %d\n",WSAGetLastError()); 
    //  fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data.\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    continue;
closesocket(client_socket);
    WSACleanup();
exit(0);
    }
/*  receive_buffer[iResult] = '\0';
    std::cout << "Receive: " <<  receive_audio << std::endl;
    Sleep(1000); */

std::cout << "Receive: " <<  (int)receive_buffer[0] << receive_buffer[1] << std::endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    Sleep(100);
}
while (!stop);


return 0;
}
```